# props.onChangeText(1, v) is not working

Tags: javascript, android, reactjs, react-native

Please how do i get the values in the text input i need to add them and divide it by the number of semesters

Here is my code

```
 <View style={styles.levelCard}>
    <Text style={styles.levelTitle}> {props.level} LEVEL </Text>
    <View style={styles.semesterRow}>
      <Text style={styles.semester}> 1st Semester </Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.semesterInput}
        maxLength={4}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        placeholder="1st Semester's GPA"
        onChangeText={(v) => props.onChangeText(1, v)} />
    </View>
    <View style={styles.semesterRow}>
      <Text style={styles.semester}> 2nd Semester </Text>
      <TextInput style={styles.semesterInput}
        keyboardType="numeric"
        maxLength={4}
        placeholder="2nd Semester's GPA"
        onChangeText={(v) => props.onChangeText(2, v)} />
    </View>
  </View>
```

Comment: Where is onChangeText defined.Post the complete code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this

```
constructor() {
  this.state = {
    semester1: 0,
    semester2: 0,
    result: 0
  }
}

onChangeText(semester, score) {
  if (semester === 1) {
    this.setState({ semester1: score })
  } else {
    this.setState({ semester2: score })
  }
  const { semester1, semester2 } = this.state;
  this.setState({
    result: (semester1 + semester2) / 2
  })
}

render() {
  return(
    <View>
      <ChildComponent onChangeText={this.onChangeText.bind(this)} />
    </View>
  )
}
```

Comment: You should be aware that checking state immediately after `setState` may not yield the result you expect. From the docs: "setState() does not always immediately update the component. It may batch or defer the update until later. This makes reading this.state right after calling setState() a potential pitfal."

Comment: And how do i call the onChangeText because its telling me can't find variable onChangeText

Comment: @Dan ah I see, I guess we need another trigger for count the result

Comment: @AzisAbdulBachar setState accepts a callback which fires after React has completed it's job `this.setState({}, () => { console.log('done') });` In the callback, it's safe to check the state variables.